# How to search current location based nearby people?

Tags: android

I've seen in many applications that after logging in using Facebook account, user can search nearby people.

Such applications can also display the distance from current location (like 1 mile away).

Ho can I achieve this kind-off search results?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [locations from a Users Facebook friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) using the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)